# SQL Server 2012 - log shipping issue

Tags: sql-server-2012, transaction-log, log-shipping

I'm sort of new to SQL Server so bear if the doubts are silly. I have configured log shipping for my DR purpose. SQL Server 2012 is the version. Today I encountered the following error in my log shipping instance.

```
   Message
2016-01-25 22:30:16.08  Searching for an older log backup file. Secondary Database: 'TwoSite'
2016-01-25 22:30:16.10  Skipped log backup file. Secondary DB: 'TwoSIte', File: 'E:\Logshipping_Backup\TwoSite\TwoSite_20160125163001.trn'
2016-01-25 22:30:16.14  Skipped log backup file. Secondary DB: 'TwoSite', File: 'E:\Logshipping_Backup\TwoSite\TwoSite_20160125161501.trn'
2016-01-25 22:30:16.15  Skipped log backup file. Secondary DB: 'TwoSite', File: 'E:\Logshipping_Backup\TwoSite\TwoSite_20160125160000.trn'
2016-01-25 22:30:16.15  *** Error: Could not find a log backup file that could be applied to secondary database 'TwoSite'.(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.LogShipping) ***
2016-01-25 22:30:16.16  Deleting old log backup files. Primary Database: 'TwoSite'
2016-01-25 22:30:16.16  The restore operation completed with errors. Secondary ID: '61a4194e-e591-459f-8466-56e42fd359e9'
2016-01-25 22:30:16.17  ----- END OF TRANSACTION LOG RESTORE     -----

Exit Status: 1 (Error)
```

I have tried to reconfiguring by taking a new full backup of primary as well. Getting the same error still.

How can this be resolved?

I can give more info if needed.

Comment: This sounds like a missing log backup.  Could it be that a process is deleting the .trn file before it actually gets shipped to the secondary.  If that were the case, then likely there was a **TwoSite_20160125154500.trn** (approximately) that was deleted prematurely.

Comment: But we don't delete t-log backups that soon. We do have retention more than a week.

Comment: Do you still have the *(conjectured by me)* **TwoSite_20160125154500.trn** available?  Or, could someone have done something to compromise  the log chain integrity?  (Delete a file by mistake, switch to SIMPLE and back to FULL recovery model, etc?)

Comment: the one which you mentioned is not available in my path..

Comment: If you want to test your log chain integrity, you can do the following:  Restore the last **TwoSite** FULL backup to **TwoSiteTest** then apply all of the **TwoSite** transaction logs to **TwoSiteTest** up to the present.  If there is no failure, then the error is elsewhere.

Comment: But when I try -- select * from msdb.dbo.log_shipping_monitor_secondary it says the last restored file is E:\Logshipping_Backup\TwoSite\TwoSite_20160125163001.trn